# SQLite in memory db not working. Table not found error

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate with nperistence api, and entity framework. Below is my persistence.xml

```
<provider>NPersistence.NHibernate.NHibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>CSharp.Node </class>
    <class>CSharp.Edge</class>

<properties>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>  
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=:memory:</property>  
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.release_mode"> on_close </property> 
        <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
```

My node class :

```
using System;
using NPersistence;

namespace CSharp
{
    [Entity]
    [Table(Name = "edge")]
    public class Edge
    {
        [Id]
        [GeneratedValue]
        public virtual int edgeId { get; set;}

        public virtual int fromnode{ get; set; }

        public virtual int tonode { get; set;}

        public virtual string edgelabel{ get; set;}

        public Edge(){
        }
    }
}
```

In most of the tutorials I found, setting connection_string=:memory: should work. But when I run my project, on querying the db I get the following error

```
NPersistence.PersistenceException: could not execute query
no such table: edge
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to also SchemaExport your database.   This will generate the schema (ie, create the tables)

Comment: How do I export the schema? I am new to this. I was previously using Sqlite (file based) and myql db, I did not export the db explicitly. I just changed the persistence.xml file without changing the code